# How to read schema of a keyspace using java.?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to read schema of a keyspace in cassandra.
I know that, in Cassandra-cli we can execute following command to get Schema

```
show schema keyspace1;
```

But i want to read schema from remote machine using java.

How i can solve this? Plzzz help me....

Comment: Are you using some client? I think it will be possible if you use some client library like Astyanax. And it is also not clear what exactly you want to do after reading Schema

Comment: I have tried by using Hector and thrift clients, but i was not able to find any API for reading schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one i solved by using thrift client

```
 KsDef keyspaceDefinition = _client.describe_keyspace(_keyspace);
 List<CfDef> columnDefinition = keyspaceDefinition.getCf_defs();
```

Here key space definition contains whole schema details, so from that KsDef we can read whatever we want. In my case i want to read metadata so i am reading column metadata from the above column definitions as shown below.

```
 for(int i=0;i<columnDefinition.size();i++){
         List<ColumnDef> columnMetadata = columnDefinition.get(i).getColumn_metadata();
        for(int j=0;j<columnMetadata.size();j++){
            columnfamilyNames.add(columnDefinition.get(i).getName());
            columnNames.add(new String((columnMetadata.get(j).getName())));
            validationClasses.add(columnMetadata.get(j).getValidation_class());
            //ar.add(coldef.get(i).getName()+"\t"+bb_to_str(colmeta.get(j).getName())+"\t"+colmeta.get(j).getValidationClass());
        }
    }
```

here columnfamilyNames, columnNames and validationClasses are arraylists.